# Riemann integral of product of sequence of function with a continuous function at a point.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity, riemann-integration, sequence-of-function

Here is the setup to a questions I've been looking at. I mainly just need a hint on how to proceed from where I'm at. Or suggest a theorem/corollaries that would help.

**The problem:**

Let $\{g_n\}$ be a sequence of nonnegative Riemann integrable function on $[-1,1]$ satisfying

1. $\int_{-1}^{1} g_n(x) dx = 1$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$
2. For every $\delta>0$, $g_n \to 0$ uniformly on $[-1,-\delta] \cup [\delta, 1]$ as $n\to \infty$.

Prove that if $\psi:[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable and continuous at $x=0$, then

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{-1}^{1} \psi(x)g_n(x)dx = \psi(0).
$$

**Attempt at solution**

So by the properties of the integral and limit, and uniform convergence of $g_n$ we have that

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{-1}^{1} \psi(x)g_n(x) dx = \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{-1}^{-\delta} \psi(x)g_n(x) dx + \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{-\delta}^{\delta} \psi(x)g_n(x) dx + \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{\delta}^{1} \psi(x)g_n(x) dx \\
=\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{-\delta}^{\delta} \psi(x)g_n(x) dx.
$$

**Question**
Am I correct in the above computations?

If so then it is clear here that I have to use condition "1" along with continuity of $\psi$ at $x=0$. However, this is where I'm entirely lost and not sure how to approach the integral
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{-\delta}^{\delta} \psi(x)g_n(x) dx
$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\psi$ is continuous at $x=0$, for any $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ that for any $|x|<\delta$, $\:|\psi(x)-\psi(0)|<\epsilon$. Also, since $\psi$ is Riemann integrable, on $[-1,-\delta] \cup [\delta, 1]$, $|\psi(x)-\psi(0)|<M$. Thus
\begin{align}
\left|\int_{-1}^{1} \psi(x)\,g_n(x)\,dx-\psi(0)\right|&=\left|\int_{-1}^{1} \psi(x)\,g_n(x)\,dx-\int_{-1}^{1} \psi(0)\,g_n(x)\,dx\right|
\\
&\leqslant\int_{-1}^{1} |\psi(x)-\psi(0)|\,g_n(x)\,dx
\\
&=\int_{-1}^{-\delta} |\psi(x)-\psi(0)|\,g_n(x)\,dx+\int_{-\delta}^{\delta} |\psi(x)-\psi(0)|\,g_n(x)\,dx+\int_{\delta}^{1} |\psi(x)-\psi(0)|\,g_n(x)\,dx
\\
&<M\int_{-1}^{-\delta} g_n(x)\,dx+ \epsilon \int_{-\delta}^{\delta} g_n(x)\,dx+M\int_{\delta}^{1} g_n(x)\,dx
\\
&<\epsilon + M\int_{-1}^{-\delta} g_n(x)\,dx+ M\int_{\delta}^{1} g_n(x)\,dx
\end{align}
Since $g_n \to 0$ uniformly on $[-1,-\delta] \cup [\delta, 1]$, there is a $N$ that for any $n>N,$
$$
\int_{-1}^{-\delta} g_n(x)\,dx<\epsilon/M\quad\text{and}\quad \int_{\delta}^{1} g_n(x)\,dx<\epsilon/M
$$
Thus
$$
\left|\int_{-1}^{1} \psi(x)\,g_n(x)\,dx-\psi(0)\right|<3\epsilon\quad\text{and}\quad\lim_{n\to \infty}\,\int_{-1}^{1} \psi(x)\,g_n(x)\,dx=\psi(0)
$$

Comment: This is basically the answer, but the first equality needs to be an inequality and I feel like making explicit when you are using condition (1) would help out OP immensely.

Comment: Just to be clear, since $\psi$ is Riemann integrable $|\psi(x) -\psi(0)|<M$ comes from $\psi$ being bounded?

Comment: @user103,thanks but the last inequality in the first string of inequalities also uses condition (1) since there is actually $\int_{-\delta} ^{\delta} g_n(x) dx$ multiplied with $\epsilon$. Otherwise good job

Comment: @user103, I know that, that is what I wanted you to add as well since you are using condition (1) for that inequality and OP implied that they are not clear on how to use condition (1) in the proof